# Outlook mail Integration, have to read the mail and click on the url present in the mail body, need to automate this using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I tried to do with Microsoft graph apis but having access issues
so I'm thinking can i do it with selenium with giving mail address and password

i tried with apis, want to know can we do it with web automation, then how to do it
Outlook mail integration is what im working on.

Comment: Selenium is for web browsers, not windows apps (Outlook). If you can reach the mailbox in browser (thin client), you can write automatic email read. For windows app automatition use Windows Application Driver https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver

Answer (score 0):

Automating outlook with selenium will gonna give you headache, as

- It is lengthy process
- Not part of your testing scope.

Use Outlook API's for that, if you are having restriction iussues with certain email, talk to your dev about it, and yes Outlook API's can be integrated with  selenium with Java and multiple other languages.
You can read documentation from below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java?context=outlook%2Fcontext&tabs=aad